# Video Encoded using FFmpeg is not being played in Azure Kinect Viewer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, azure-sdk, azurekinect

I captured a video using a `Kinect Azure SDK` device and extracted the RGB (Color) track using `MKVToolNIX`. I could playback this RGB track using `Azure Kinect Viewer (v.1.4.1)`. However, when I encode a video using `FFmpeg`, the command is given below. I can not playback the video using Azure Kinect Viewer. I get a message:

> Failed to open Recording

```
ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 128k RGG_Enc.mkv
```

I tried with different codecs (H.264, H.265, VP9, VP10, MJPEG) and different settings, but could not play the video in `Azure Kinect Viewer`. Can someone suggest to me what to do?

Here is the output of the `FFprobe` for the original video.

```
  C:\Users\Ashutosh\Desktop\RGB_Encoding> ffprobe -i .\RGB.mkv
  ffprobe version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007- 
 2023 the FFmpeg developers
 built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static -- 
 disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig -- 
 enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp -- 
 enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib -- 
 enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq -- 
 enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 
 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable- 
 libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 -- 
 enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 
 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable- 
 libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable- 
 libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi -- 
 enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable- 
 libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable- 
 ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable- 
 dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan -- 
 enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme 
 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb 
 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable- 
 libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable- 
 libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable- 
 libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b -- 
 enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband -- 
 enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint

 libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
 libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
 libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
 libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
 libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
 libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
 libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
 libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

 [matroska,webm @ 0000018ef5f4e240] Could not find codec parameters 
 for stream 1 (Attachment: none): unknown codec
 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 
 'probesize' (5000000) options

 Input #0, matroska,webm, from '.\RGB.mkv':
 Metadata:
 title           : Azure Kinect
 encoder         : libebml v1.4.4 + libmatroska v1.7.1
 creation_time   : 2023-08-04T11:52:43.000000Z
 Duration: 00:00:40.03, start: 0.033000, bitrate: 126708 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), 
 yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2048x1536, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 
 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
 
 Metadata:
 title           : COLOR
  BPS             : 126696930
  DURATION        : 00:00:40.029000000
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1201
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 633943931
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v76.0 ('Celebration') 64-bit
  _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2023-08-04 11:52:43
  _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES

Stream #0:1: Attachment: none
Metadata:
  filename        : calibration.json
  mimetype        : application/octet-stream
 Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
```

This [example video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pmZmExeBkSsPr4hnO2SgCmWjyx3uNToe/view?usp=sharing) contains only one channel (RGB) from the original video. I am able to play this video using Azure Kinect Viewer.

Comment: **(1)** Azure Kinect Viewer seems to use an [RGB image format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/hardware-specification#color-camera-supported-operating-modes). What you call an _"RGB track"_ might actually be a JPEG track. It's also possible that Azure Kinetic does not support reading or writing of any H.264 (MPEG) video data. **(2)** _"I tried with different codecs"_ That doesn't tell us if you tried using RGB as the codec... **(3)** You need a smaller example file. It cannot be half a gigabyte. Try 100MB as max size. This means create a new test file of a few seconds length.

Comment: I added the output of the FFprobe for the original video and added the codecs that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

> *"However, when I encode a video using **FFmpeg**...  
> I can not playback the video using **Azure Kinect Viewer**."*

It's possible that FFmpeg does not encode files that are compatible with Azure Kinetic Viewer.

**Azure Kinect Viewer** seems to expect: an **MKV** file containing **YUV** or **JPEG** data as frames

The fastest way to solve this problem is to **recreate the structure** of a known working file (that plays in Azure Kinetic Viewer) but replace those existing internal frames with your own custom frames (*eg:* providing your encoded video in single frames).

This means:

- Record a uniform **flat** colour (all white or all green) whose pixel values you can find later on.
- Make a very short (seconds) RGB track that plays Azure Kinetic Viewer.
- Open the same file (RGB track) using a **Hex editor** (on Windows you can try: [HxD Viewer](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20)).
- Pay attention to the bytes before your RGB data (here RGB could be YUV or JPEG).
- Pay attention means check for possible entries for: duration, total frames, frame lengths, etc..
- What happens when you replace one frame with your own encoded one?

You will need to provide a testable file for further advice.

**If not sure what format of RGB data:**

(or you could check the output settings in your Kinect setup options)

The Hex editor shows you the file structure (in bytes). In the editor, find bytes that represent your recorded colour (*eg:* find the first frame):

- If you've got JPEG then find bytes starting as `FF D8 FF` (for JPEG start code)
- If you've got RGB then find your recorded colour by its hex code (*eg:* Green is `00 FF 00`).
- Otherwise assume your data is YUV format (if non of the other above options are found)

Comment: If I look at the output obtained from FFprobe, It is YUV422. I checked the `Hex editor` and the first line looks like this `1A 45 DF A3 A3 42 86 81 01 42 F7 81 01 42 F2 81`.
So, I guess, it is a YUV format.

Comment: _"I extracted the RGB (Color) track using **MKVToolNIX**"_ So you're the one that calls it `RGB.mkv` even though it could be just YUV images in there? First I thought it's shocking that there isn't any header or metadata bytes, but I suspect the RGB track is now just a sequence of YUV image data (frames). If true, you can recreate that with FFmpeg. But how will the frame rate and picture size be known by the player? That's why I suspect there is more data...

Comment: The original video has three streams (Color (RGB), Depth, and Infrared). The `pixel_format` for the Color (RGB) track is `yuvj422p`. It is available in `.mkv` container.

Comment: You can try (without audio): `ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -pix_fmt yuv422p -an RGB_Enc.mkv` (PS: can replace `yuv422p` with `mjpeg`) does that file work with the Player? Also I wonder if the Kinetic player expects all 3 tracks to exist before it accepts any MKV input as a valid file?

Comment: Azure Kinect player can play a single track without any issue. If I use your command above, I get an error `failed to open the recording`. I am using these commands now `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy -f mjpeg imm.meh` and then remuxing it with `ffmpeg -i imm.meh -c:v copy out.mkv`. The player shows a blank screen. I do not receive an error in this case.

Comment: Again... You **need to recreate** the state of the working file. When you say _"...Extracted the RGB (Color) track"_ did you get an MKV file? That MKV works in the Kinetic Player, correct? But when you open that MKV in the hex editor you see these first bytes: `1A 45 DF A3 A3 42 86 81 01 42 F7 81 01 42 F2 81`, correct? Looking in a hex editor does the **second line** have any text like `matroska` (or bytes: `6D 61 74 72 6F 73 6B 61`) if yes then your data is a Matroska MKV file. The file format is not YUV data as suspected by your first comment. It does later contain YUV in one its tracks.

Comment: PS: What problem are you really trying to solve by doing this? So `RGB.mkv` is the working (in Kinetic) file, but you want to use it as input for FFmpeg to output a new MKV that also works in Kinetic? Why the FFmpeg step? Maybe there is a better solution. PPS Try: `ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -codec copy RGB_Enc.mkv` Now does the output `RGB_Enc.mkv` work in the Kinetic player?

Comment: I would like to play an encoded version of the RGB.mkv in Azure Kinect Viewer. The encoded video does not work. If I analyze the `metadata` between the `original` and the `encoded` video, I see the difference in `Encoder`. `Ori_Vid_Encoder: libebml v1.4.4 + libmatroska v1.7.1` and `Enc_Vid_Encoder: Lavf60.3.100`.

Comment: When I extracted the RGB track, I got an `MKV` file and it works in `Kinect Player`. If I open the file in a hex editor, the bytes that you mentioned are correct and the second line has a text like `matroska`. I have provided the extracted RGB track in an MKV file, please see my question.

Comment: Your example file is 600MB. No one is going scroll through 600 million bytes just for fun. Please add a smaller example file (**5 seconds or less**). The idea is to check the structure of a complete (but very short) MKV that plays in Kinetic...  PS: _"I analyze the metadata between..."_ It's possible that your metadata analysing program might be skipping some bytes (_eg:_ unknown custom bytes that Kinetic still expects to read from the MKV file). PPS: Using `codec copy` should have recreated an exact copy, if that new `copy` re-encode does not play in Kinetic then FFmpeg is not a solution.

Comment: PS: To make a smaller RGB file, choose a resolution of: `1280x720` (not current: `2048x1536)`. That should halve the output file size (compared to using a higher res). Please confirm: Using `ffmpeg -i .\RGB.mkv -codec copy RGB_Enc.mkv` produced a **not working** file in Kinetic, true or false? If true/not-working, then FFmpeg is wrong solution, you need to manually insert your own encoded MJPEG frames into an MKV structure that plays in Kinetic.. Note: Kinetic Player and FFmpeg might be looking at (and looking for) different things inside the same file. What needed **extra bytes** are missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255527/discussion-between-ashutosh-singla-and-vc-one).

Comment: Thanks for awarding. I will focus more on this soon in 1 or 2 days (got to first finish work for a client). All I found so far is that the MKV has 3 or 4 sections. There was an EBML header (as found in all MKV files) but then you also had a block of some text called `calibration.json`, then a block for the MJPEG data, then another block of unknown data (could be MKV related) and possibly there was a 4th block of data. I will re-check when I get a chance. The point being... Make sure your FFmpeg produced MKV has a matching structure (it's okay if names/sizes are different from original)

Comment: PS: If possible then leave FFmpeg out and just write a quick program to slice bytes of your MKV into blocks. Slice from block **ID** up to block's data ending (by data **LENGTH**). Put each block in its own Array and then edit any such block's array separately. Eg: the block with MJPEG data could be edited to add/remove frames. When finished update the LENGTH (the first few starting byte values in this array). Update the LENGTH of the other array that holds the EBML header (eg: sum up the total lengths of all arrays for FILE SIZE entry). Join arrays  --> Save file --> Test in Kinetic player.

Comment: PPS: Useful references **(a)** [How to find blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75382896/2057709), **(b)** [doc: MKV layout](https://matroska.org/technical/diagram.html) (you are interested in **Cluster** and **Track** elements) **(c)** [doc: Element magic-word(s)](https://matroska.org/technical/elements.html) (the byte values needed to find any elements).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this out tomorrow.